# Validate request body in Nginx

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka

I am using Nginx as a producer which receives requests and sends them to Kafka.

For this purpose I found [ngx_kafka_module](https://github.com/brg-liuwei/ngx_kafka_module) for Nginx.

Is it possible to validate request body in Nginx? Because the [ngx_kafka_module](https://github.com/brg-liuwei/ngx_kafka_module) puts what was in the request body to the Kafka. I want to remove fields that don't exist in my scheme.

Comment: you mean blocking public users from accessing it ?

Comment: @IAmBatman updated my question. Could you answer now?